# How to delete all the rows of the DataFrame except the first row and the last row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to delete all rows of my DataFrame except the first and the last one regardless of its size

```
Input
1
2
3
4
5
.
.
999999999

Expected output:

1
999999999
```

Comment: Maybe its best to just extract the first and last row: `df = df.loc[[0,len(df)-1]].reset_index()`  ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use iloc

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
    "Input": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(f"{df}\n")


df = df.iloc[[0, -1]].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)

   Input
0      1
1      8
```